# Zero-inflated Negative Binomial Model in Rethinking

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rethinking-r-package

I am looking for help/resources to guide me on how to change this zero-inflate Poisson model into zero-inflated negative binomial model in Rethinking. I don't see a function like dzipois that would easily take care of this issue. Could I somehow use dgampois in a zero-inflated negative binomial model? Any ideas? Thank you!!!

```
SitePoisson <- ulam(
  alist(
    SportfishCount ~ dzipois(pbar, lamba), 
    logit(pbar) <- z1 + z2*Dim2
    log(lamba)a + b*Dim1 + c*Dim2 + d*HTOY, 
    a ~ dnorm(1.85, 2.76), 
    b ~ dnorm(1, 100), 
    c ~ dnorm(1, 100), 
    d ~ dnorm(0, 1), 
    c(z1, z2) ~ dnorm(0, 1)
  ), 
  data=ModelData, 
  start=list(a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, z1=0.1, z2=0.2), 
  iter=5000, warmup=2000, chains=3, cores=4, log_lik=TRUE
)
```

I've read as much as I could, but I am not finding any information on zero-inflated negative binomial models in bayesian techniques.

Comment: Maybe `pscl::zeroinfl(..., dist = "negbin",...)` will helps

Comment: Are you committed to using rethinking or would you be OK with using Stan or brms? It is pretty easy to do in brms (`brms::zero_inflated_negbinomial()`)

Comment: Come to think of it, you could just use `brms::dzero_inflated_negbinomial()` in place of your current `dzipois()`. But you do have to keep in mind there is an extra parameter. Instead of just `pbar` and `lambda` you will now have `pbar`, `mu`, and `shape` so you would have to write a separate likelihood statement for `mu` and `shape` where you currently just have the one for `lambda`.

Comment: I am more committed to Stan since that is what my colleagues use.

Comment: Looks like `log(lamba)a` misses an operator.

Comment: Try looking at [the code for `dzipois`](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/blob/2f01a9c5dac4bc6e9a6f95eec7cae268200a8181/R/distributions.r#L278) and refactor to use `dgampois` (i.e., negative binomial).

Comment: If you are committed to `stan` than `brms` or `stan` directly could be your solution. Also `brms` will generate the `stan` code for you.